# Using a proxy to access the dataset of a custom element

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, custom-element, proxies

Imagine this trivial custom element:

```
<my-el data-cute-number="7" id="foo"></my-el>
```

`document.getElementById('foo').dataset.cuteNumber`, as expected, returns the String "7". I would like to create a proxy for accessing dataset properties that does the casting to `Number` for me because I'm using the property alot in the component code and would like to avoid repeatedly having to cast it manually every time I access it. I also do not want to create an additional getter for a new property (e.g. `get cuteNumber() { return Number(this.dataset.cuteNumber); }`) on the component itself since I will have to do all the synchronisation manually then (since I'd also need a setter), make sure I avoid infinite update loops, etc.

As I understand proxies, this is exactly where a proxy will help me.

```js
customElements.define('my-el', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    const proxy = new Proxy(this.dataset, {
      get: function(context, prop, receiver) {
        console.log(`Proxy getter executing for ${prop}`);
        switch (prop) {
          case 'cuteNumber':
            return Number(context[prop]);
            break;
          default: 
            return context[prop];
        }
      }
    });
  }
})

console.log(typeof document.getElementById('foo').dataset.cuteNumber);
```

```html
<my-el data-cute-number="7" id="foo"></my-el>
```

This is where I'm stuck.

Accessing the `dataset` currently does not trigger the proxy (the inner `console.log` doesn't show up).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Is it even possible to proxy the `dataset` of an element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a proxy does not mutate the target object, it doesn't *become* a proxy. The proxy is a new object that wraps around the target. In your code, you are just throwing away the `proxy` and never use it - the `.dataset` property is unaffected. You'll want to either overwrite it or create a new property:

```js
customElements.define('my-el', class extends HTMLElement {
  get dataset() {
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return new Proxy(super.dataset, {
//  ^^^^^^
      get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
        console.log(`Proxy getter executing for ${prop}`);
        if (prop == 'cuteNumber')
          return Number(target.cuteNumber);
        return Reflect.get(target, prop, receiver);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(typeof document.getElementById('foo').dataset.cuteNumber);
```

```html
<my-el data-cute-number="7" id="foo"></my-el>
```

```js
customElements.define('my-el', class extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.numberdata = new Proxy(this.dataset, {
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      get: function(target, prop, receiver) {
        return Number(target[prop]);
      }
    });
  }
});

console.log(typeof document.getElementById('foo').numberdata.cuteNumber);
```

```html
<my-el data-cute-number="7" id="foo"></my-el>
```

Comment: So it doesn't work for `dataset`  because it is read-only, correct?

Comment: I guess you can create an own property on the instance by using `Object.defineProperty`, ignoring the setter. But there's a better solution... See my edit.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that wouldn't modify the way I need to access the dataset, at all. Having this intermediate object that does the proxying doesn't feel any better than creating mirrored properties on the element itself.

Comment: Your edit is looking good, except is it necessary to create a new Proxy on every read access to `dataset`?

Comment: @connexo You could also cache them in a `WeakMap` or on a (symbol?) property of the element, instantiating it either in the constructor (like in the second snippet) or lazily on first access. I don't what the overhead of proxy objects is, it might not matter maybe (unless you want to ensure that `element.dataset === element.dataset` holds)? You might want to put the `handler` object literal in a static `const` outside of the class though.